# How to delete a wamp virtual site?

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

With the new WAMP, you have to create a virtual host site to see it in localhost development. Which I did, and it worked.
However, I just moved that website to a Live server, and I cannot, for the life of me, see the website in my browser. I get a message:

> This site can’t be reached

My friends see it, but it cannot be seen by the development computer.

I tried :

- Deleting the definition in `httpd-vhosts`
- Rebooting
- Flushing Windows 10 DNS cache

All to no avail. And I cannot find information about deleting a website from WAMP!!! Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

It may be due to the hostname duplicate. Edit the virtual host to fix this.

For windows users, edit your virtual host from

C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

and

C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra

To edit these files you need to run as administrator. To do this, try the following steps:

1. Press the Windows key.
2. Type Notepad in the search field.
3. In the search results, right-click Notepad and select Run as administrator.
4. From Notepad, open the following file: 
        c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.
5. Make the necessary changes to the file.
6. Click File > Save to save your changes.

Finally restart the server.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you use a local domain name that is the same as your live sites domain name i.e. `mysite.com` rather than `mysite.dev`

So you will have added a line to your HOSTS file like this

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
::1  mysite.com
```

So from your PC you have told windows your site lives locally on this PC.

All you need to do is remove those 2 lines from your `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and then either reboot or run (from an admin acoount)

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Now Windows does not know where `yoursite.com` lives and it will ask a DNS Server for the LIVE sites IP Address, and find your live site.

Comment: You may have to run your editor in administrator mode in order to save the hosts file. Find the link to open your editor, then rt-click -> Run as Administrator.  I use Notepad++, and it helpfully gives a message that it must be run in administrator mode, then gives an option to open a new instance of the editor in administrator mode, and re-opens the file in the new instance if you chose yes, saving a step.

Answer (score 2):

[Babitha's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913428/2227743) is correct but I had to make these changes:

For both you need to edit them as administrator
C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
Don't just come paste your apache version can be diffrent and your wamp location in another place.

Edit virtual host that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but for me worked:
- clear targeted vhost in etc/hosts.
- clear targeted vhost in httpd-vhosts.conf.
- Restart DNS wamp tool (RMB wamp icon->Tools).
- Restart all services.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Wamp has an option to do this.
With Wamp running, click on the Wamp Icon roll over "Your VirtualHosts" and click on "VirtualHost management". This opens the screen to add a new virtual host. On the right hand side are three additional options - one of which is "Delete VirtualHost form" (the other 2 are "Modify VirtualHost form" and "Modify Alias form"
Clicking on "Delete VirtualHost form" button brings up a list of your virtual hosts. Check the one(s) you want to remove and click the "Delete VirtualHost" button.

Voila - it's gone